# Horizontal menu fit 100%, text stack to the left

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have an horizontal menu and I can't find the way to make it fit with the 100% of my centered container page (from left side to right side).
Also I want every **html main lists** to get at the left side of the horizontal menu.

I think it's something related to my CSS code...

Right now my website looks like this: [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOyso.png)

```css
body {
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
}
h1 {
  color: #FCFCFC;
  padding-left: 8px;
  background-color: 494949;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 0px 7px 0px;
  /* margen arriba , margen dercha, margen abajo, margen izquierda  */
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #C69AD3;
  /*sombra color del solido*/
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #353535;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: bottom;
}
p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0, 5px 0, 5px #343434
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  /*   colocacion del header en los id="header"  */
  padding: 0px;
  /*   colocacion del header en los id="header"  */
}
#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
#header {
  background: #545;
  margin: 3px 5px 3px 0x;
  /* margen arriba , margen dercha, margen abajo, margen izquierda  */
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #494949;
}
ul,
ol {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  /* con el "list-style:none" hacemos que no se vean puntos ni otras formas en las listas, de modo que las palabras quedan solas en forma de lista. */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav > li {
  float: left;
  /*posicion del menu horizontal*/
}
.nav li a {
  background-color: 494949;
  /*Color botones menú sin seleccion*/
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* quitamos el subrallado */
  padding: 10px 100px;
  /* altura y anchura del menu */
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
  /* margen arriba , margen dercha, margen abajo, margen izquierda  */
}
.nav li a:hover {
  /* "hover" es cuando tienes el mouse encima*/
  background-color: #6B6B6B;
}
.nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* posicion en cuando se despliega el menu, absolute=se abre y no mueve nada, relative=se desplaza todo objeto que este debajo */
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav li ul li ul {
  right: -140px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Practica A3</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo1.css" />

</head>

<div id="container">

  <h1 class="center">Hello this is the website</h1>

  <body>

    <div id="header">
      <nav class="menu-fixed">
        <!-- Iniciamos la etiqueta del menu -->
        <ul class="nav">
          <!-- Inicio TODO -->
          <li><a href="">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <!-- Principal -->
          <li><a href="">Servicios</a> 
            <!-- Principal -->
            <ul>
              <!-- Inicio secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Compra de entradas</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Consulta de conciertos</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Salas privadas</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Reserva de mesas</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
            </ul>
            <!-- Final secundaria -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Acerca de</a> 
            <!-- Principal -->
            <ul>
              <!-- Inicio secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Submenu1</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Submenu2</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Submenu3</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
            </ul>
            <!-- Final secundaria -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Contacto</a>
          </li>
          <!-- Principal -->
        </ul>
        <!-- Final TODO -->
      </nav>
      <!-- Cerramos el menu con la nav -->
    </div>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>


    <p>Este es contenido de la pagina web. Simplemente se trata de un texto laaaaaaargo para ver como se posiciona y que tal quedaria con el resultado final.</br>
      Esto es todo, gracias por la atencion.</p>

  </body>

</div>

</html>
```

Comment: can you explain please. Why you placed <header> tag before the body tag. and close one </div> out side body tag?? And why you used <center>tag before div id  #header

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Hello! Thanks for answer... Well I dont know, I didnt realize and I think now its fixed. But while "Run code snippet" in this website doesnt look the same way I do in my computer while I execute it from the Notepad++ with Google Chrome!

This is how I can see my html: https://i.gyazo.com/225aa272f44dcd3dd11da1b26826b09b.png

Comment: You still have a div outside body tag. Please Add a screen shot with your question If you think it's not fixed yet.

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Well that div is outside the body because I want the all witdh of the page at 80%. I add you my screenshot of my question:
http://i.imgur.com/eHB4aVU.png

Comment: Body contain all the element of page. So if you want that. you can write the code like this <body><div id="container"> Write all the code</div><!--#container Div End--></body>. Take a test with w3c you html .[ https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input ] . you will find 11 error.

Answer (score 0):

[Also Live on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v05h3Lvf/)Your navbar is get the full-width(80%) of container. Now the problem is you set the h1 and .center class width 100% with border-bottom. If you remove the width of h1 and .center class it will get inside the container width. 
And the menu text center issue set the .nav li a {padding: 10px 100px 10px 10px;} like this. Also in your css some useless property which I comment out in css part and also try to give a short description with comment.
If you have any question regarding this . you can ask me in comment section. Thanks

```css
body {
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
}

h1 {
  color: #FCFCFC;
  padding-left: 8px;
  background-color: #494949;
  /*In here you don't set # so the color not showing */
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 0px 7px 0px;
  /* margen arriba , margen dercha, margen abajo, margen izquierda  */
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #C69AD3;
  /*sombra color del solido*/
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #353535;
  /* font-size: 200%; [By default h1 font-size 2em means 200% so I don't think you need to use it again ] */
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  /*text-align: bottom; [This css is invalid. Three types is valid text-align: left/center/right]*/
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0, 5px 0, 5px #343434
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  /*   colocacion del header en los id="header"  */
  padding: 0px;
  /*   colocacion del header en los id="header"  */
}

#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*text-align: left; [it means inside all text element will be align left. Don't use it here. User where you need. ] */
    }
  #header {
     background: #545;
  /*   margin: 3px 5px 3px 0x; [This margin will be invalid coz you missed the "P" from last 0px] */
  /* margen arriba , margen dercha, margen abajo, margen izquierda  */
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #494949;
}


/*Change ul,ol class like this other wise if you have any other list item in your body section will be effected. This is also a example of valid css selctor. */

ul.nav,
.nav li ul {
  list-style: none;
  /* con el "list-style:none" hacemos que no se vean puntos ni otras formas en las listas, de modo que las palabras quedan solas en forma de lista. */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav > li {
  float: left;
  /*posicion del menu horizontal*/
}

.nav li a {
  background-color: #494949;
  /*Again in here you don't set # so the color not showing */
  /*Color botones menú sin seleccion*/
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* quitamos el subrallado */
  padding: 10px 100px 10px 10px;
  /*This is for the left to right menu*/
  /* altura y anchura del menu */
  display: block;
  /*margin: 0px 0px 1px 1px; [This is margin create the gap between every li a tag if you want that gap you can use this.*/
  /* margen arriba , margen dercha, margen abajo, margen izquierda  */
}

.nav li a:hover {
  /* "hover" es cuando tienes el mouse encima*/
  background-color: #6B6B6B;
}

.nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* posicion en cuando se despliega el menu, absolute=se abre y no mueve nada, relative=se desplaza todo objeto que este debajo */
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav li ul li ul {
  right: -140px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Practica A3</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo1.css" />

</head>

   <body>
<div id="container">

  <h1 class="center">Hello this is the website</h1>
    <div id="header">
      <nav class="menu-fixed">
        <!-- Iniciamos la etiqueta del menu -->
        <ul class="nav">
          <!-- Inicio TODO -->
          <li><a href="">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <!-- Principal -->
          <li><a href="">Servicios</a> 
            <!-- Principal -->
            <ul>
              <!-- Inicio secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Compra de entradas</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Consulta de conciertos</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Salas privadas</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Reserva de mesas</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
            </ul>
            <!-- Final secundaria -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Acerca de</a> 
            <!-- Principal -->
            <ul>
              <!-- Inicio secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Submenu1</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Submenu2</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Submenu3</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
              <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
              </li>
              <!-- Secundaria -->
            </ul>
            <!-- Final secundaria -->
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Contacto</a>
          </li>
          <!-- Principal -->
        </ul>
        <!-- Final TODO -->
      </nav>
      <!-- Cerramos el menu con la nav -->
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


    <p>Este es contenido de la pagina web. Simplemente se trata de un texto laaaaaaargo para ver como se posiciona y que tal quedaria con el resultado final.<br>Esto es todo, gracias por la atencion.</p>

    </div><!--End #Container DIV -->
  </body>
 </html>
```